# PHP via command line outputs source code

Tags: php, debian

After recently updating to Debian 8.0, and hence `PHP 5.6 (PHP 5.6.7-1 (cli) (built: Mar 24 2015 12:30:15))`

A bunch of my PHP scripts seem to have broken. Most specifically, now when running a PHP script through the command line, it seems to simply output the actual script. I think it might have something to do with the new php.ini that (mistakenly)  got installed. But I'm not sure exactly what I'm missing..

```
[server~] php5 p.php
<?
exec("whoami");
?>

[server~] /usr/bin/php p.php
<?
exec("whoami");
?>

[server~] ./p.php
<?
exec("whoami");
?>

[server~] cat p.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
exec("whoami");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using short tags `<?`.  Get used to using `<?php` to open PHP code blocks.

You can change the setting in php.ini under `short_open_tag`.  But I think it is better practice to use `<?php`.

Comment: Thanks. I literally just figured this out as you commented.